# How can I set the permissions for blogs in Orchard CMS?

Tags: permissions, blogs, roles, orchardcms

I'm using the Orchard CMS for a system that needs to maintain a couple of blogs. I created a bunch of users and for each user I also created a blog. The owner for each of the blogs is set to the corresponding user.

All these users have the Author role associated so when I log in with one of these users I want to be able to create blog posts for that specific blog. However, I don't see the Create new Blog Post option in the panel. If I add the Manage Blogs permission to the Author role I can see all the blogs and define content for each of those (but I don't like the idea because I don't want users to be able to modify the content in other blogs than the one associated with their username). How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are "edit own" and "edit any" permissions for that reason. "Manage blogs" should not be necessary to create posts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I knew I should not use 'Manage blogs'. The Author role has by default these permissions assigned: 'Edit own blog posts', 'Edit own blog posts' and 'Delete own blog post'. However if I enter the dashboard with a user that has this Role I don't see any options for blog posts (the owner of the blog is set to that specific user). If from the blog properties I choose to display the blog in the admin menu I can see it but I still cannot add content to that blog (and if I have two blogs I see both of the options in the menu although the user is owner for only one of the blogs

Comment: That's a bug then. Can you please file it on the issue tracker?

Answer (score 1):

you have to check the "Show on admin menu" in the blog configuration page (above the owner setting)
then you can have a link of that blog at the left panel in the dashboard, click that link you will be able to add new posts